# Vertical-align bottom not working in a table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is a bootstrap row. I want to vertically align a  to the bottom of the div, however it is still aligned to the top of the row div.

Code:

```
    <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;display:table-cell;vertical-align: bottom;">
        <h4 style="color:#FFF;vertical-align: bottom;">*Stuff like restaurants, meat alternatives, dairy alternatives, and much more!</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Why is this code not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="display:table;">
    <h4 style="color:#000; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">*Stuff like restaurants, meat alternatives, dairy alternatives, and much more!</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `display:table` to parent `div.row`
also add body & html Height 100%;

```
<div class="row" style="height:100%; display: table;">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:100%;display:table-cell;vertical-align: bottom;">
        <h4 style="color:#FFF;vertical-align: bottom;">*Stuff like restaurants, meat alternatives, dairy alternatives, and much more!</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mjaty6u7/